# /dev/fedora/root does not exist, /dev/fedora/swap does not exist, /dev/mapper/fedora-root does not exist

Tags: fedora, filesystems, lvm

I removed a pre-installed Windows 10 to install Fedora 26 on my Lenovo Yoga 9.

Now, the computer doesn't boot. Gets stuck during the boot and it shows this: 
[image: The screen where the computer gets stuck]

Can Someone please tell me what I should do to fix this? I am completely new to Fedora. I intend to remove Windows 10 and keep Fedora 26.

Comment: What is the output of `pvs` `lvs` and `vgs`? Please add it to your question.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get the output of pvs lvs and vgs. Really sorry for asking this apparently silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this it. The problem was that while installing Fedora 26, I didn't do the partitioning properly. I left almost all of my hard drive space unpartitioned/free and had little to none for boot, swap etc.

So all I had to do was reinstall Fedora 26 with proper partitioning and the problem was solved. I mainly followed the following two links:

1. https://www.tecmint.com/fedora-25-installation-guide/
2. [https://www.tecmint.com/fedora-24-workstation-installation-guide/](https://www.tecmint.com/fedora-25-installation-guide/)

Proper partition is important!

Comment: Hmmm; the installer _should_ have warned you about that. Did it?

Comment: As far as I remember, I received no such warnings

Comment: Which partitioning option did you use? (Guided, or blivit)?